# Looking for a smart adjective

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a short adjective or adjective phrase to convey the following description:

> "When we borrow a solution from another domain to solve a problem that
> is not relevant but we have no choice.

This solution is ... **(adjective or adjective phrase)**

Any suggestions for how to fill this blank space with a smart substitute. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Provisional**

> for the present time but likely to change:

*These dates are only provisional.*

[Cambridge Dictionary]

Answer (score 2):

The closest is probably [**makeshift**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/makeshift)

"As an adjective, 1680s, "of the nature of a temporary expedient," which led to the noun sense of "that with which one meets a present need or turn, a temporary substitute" (by 1802)."

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been transposed.

> Transpose =
>
> 1 : to change the relative place or normal order of
>
> 2 : to change in form or nature : TRANSFORM
>
> 3 : to render into another language, style, or manner of expression : TRANSLATE
>
> 4 : to transfer from one place or period to another : SHIFT
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transpose#synonyms)

Although these definitions do not all explicitly express it, they all are consistent with the sense that something has been taken from its normal place and applied elsewhere.